# Divide a Number in two columns in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a Column Vector of numbers un my python environment like this:

```
400657
400658
400659
400660
400661
...
```

I want to divide this numbers in two columns like this:

```
number 1 number 2
400      657
400      658
400      659
400      660
400      661
...      ...
```

But i don´t know how do this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array = [400657, 400658, 400659, 400660, 400661]
n = 3
first_column = list(map(lambda x: int(str(x)[:n]), array))
second_column = list(map(lambda x: int(str(x)[n:]), array))
```

Explanation: I use slices to get first `n` and last digits of number. Using [map](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) this code generates two lists that you need from original one.

Comment: Mmmm, is a good answer, but i want to use this for all cases in general, not just this case, i need a form to divide one number in two numbers based on the number of digits i need

Comment: ah, understood. what if number of digits is odd? do all items in list have the same digits count?

Comment: The digits i need are the first three digits, because 400 is equal in all numbers.

Comment: do you mean that you want to split number to first n digits and last x digits where n is configurable?

Comment: Exactly, this is it